# A book about man controlling humans with mind power/amplifier

Tags: story-identification, mind-control, telepathy, cold-war

I remember very little, and that little might be wrong , but here's what I remember :

In the US some man has mind power (or maybe invents something for that purpose) using which he can control another man's will. Then he builds thought amplifiers and starts to control a village, then continues expanding. At the same time somewhere in the USSR another guy invents the same technology (or maybe has the same ability), so this good guy comes to the US and helps beating the bad one.

Can anyone remember the name of that book?

Comment: (Approximately) when did you read it? Was it new then? Short story, thin novel, doorstopper-sized novel?

Comment: Hmm I must've missed notification, sorry.
I read it around 15 years ago, it was thin novel as I remember, not short story or doorstopper.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be "[Tool of the Trade](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/423099.Tool_of_the_Trade)" by Joe Haldeman?

The main character invents some device for controlling minds. I don't recall there being a second character in the USSR, but the CIA and KGB are involved somehow.

[image]

Comment: I recently read *Tool of the Trade* -- sometime in the last year -- and yes, there is KGB involvement.  I don't think they developed their own mind-control device; IIRC, someone figured out how the American device worked, and a KGB agent was able to subvert its power.

Comment: I looked up "Tool of the Trade" on wikipedia, it seems like an interesting book to read, but unfortunately not what I was looking for. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I remember a book back in the late 70's... It was called [Star Fire](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/687730.Star_Fire) by Ingo Swann. I had a friend draw the front cover on the front of a T-shirt and the back cover on the back of the same T-Shirt.

[image: T-shirt version]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what the T-shirt adds to the answer...

Comment: Unfortunately not the book I was searching for but it's going to be my next read , thanks alot..